# После append обновить содержимое окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть корзина на js в которой товары добавляются методом append.

Добавленные товары видны, только если закрыть и открыть корзину.

Каким образом можно обновлять корзину, чтобы добавленные товары были сразу видны?

**P.S. корзина реализована во всплывающем окне**

скрипт корзины - http://ruwolkinzcom.1spa.by/js/jquery.mycart.js

вызов корзины

```
$(function () {

      var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
          var $cartIcon = $(".my-cart-icon");
          var $image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "fixed", "z-index": "999"});
          $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
          var position = $cartIcon.position();
          $image.animate({
              top: position.top,
              left: position.left
          }, 500 , "linear", function() {
              $image.remove();
          });
      }

      $('.my-cart-btn').myCart({
          classCartIcon: 'my-cart-icon',
          classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
          affixCartIcon: true,
          checkoutCart: function(products) {
              $.each(products, function(){
                  console.log(this);
              });
          },
          clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart){
              goToCartIcon($addTocart);
          },
          getDiscountPrice: function(products) {
              var total = 0;
              $.each(products, function(){
                  total += this.quantity * this.price;
              });
              return total * 0.5;
          }
      });

  });
```

Comment: Мало информации, покажите свой код, явно какой-то скрипт отвечает за обновление корзины

Comment: добавил скрипт корзины